# HTML multiple frame targeting

Tags: html, frame, target

Is it possible to click on a link and open three different pages targeting three different frames? So far, i am able to open two different pages to target two different frames using the standard href combined with the onclick function with the location.href

I'm not talking about opening multiple windows in a new window/tab since that can simply be done by creating many onclick functions, what i want is to be able to open three(or more, hopefully) different pages and target them towards three different frames as well.

Comment: if you done it for 2, then whats wrong with third one

Comment: Since i can only target a different frame using the standard href, while the onclick location.href loads the page where that link is on. so basically it's stuck to target on that same frame.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have this markup:

```
<iframe src="">
<iframe src="">
<iframe src="">
```

You could then have some simple JS as such to change the `src` and URL and "target" those three frames in the markup, as such (getting a zero-indexed nodelist and targeted them that way through a selector):

```
document.getElementsByName("iframe")[0].src="http://whateverurl.com/'";
document.getElementsByName("iframe")[1].src="http://whateverurl.com/'";
document.getElementsByName("iframe")[2].src="http://whateverurl.com/'";
```

Could be used in a `a` like this: `<a href='#' onclick='document.getElementsByName("iframe")[0].src="http://whateverurl.com/'"; document.getElementsByName("iframe")[1].src="http://whateverurl.com/'"; document.getElementsByName("iframe")[2].src="http://whateverurl.com/'";'>testlink</a>`

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? If it was, feel free to mark it as the correct answer with the checkmark.

Comment: hmm i didn't quite get it since i am not that much familiar with JS, but uhm let's say we have three frames. frame(1), frame(2) and frame(3)

Let's put the button on frame(1). Clicking it will open 3 different pages to each frame.